# Don't see much difference in size

Tags: weight-loss, diet

Been working out for about 2-3 months. Doing stuff like gyming, weights, cardio like running and jogging. Dropped to 93kg from 105. I was about 33% body fat when i was 105, although i'm not sure what i am right now. Also been eating generally clean like steamed chicken and grilled salmon and veggies and stuff.

I would assume i need to lose around 15 to 20kg more of fat to get the physique i am aiming for, however my size doesn't seem to have gone down despite losing about 10kg. So i'm just wondering how much smaller would I even get if i were to lose the 15/20kg of body fat, and any tips to make it more visible. Assuming I'm not a very strong person and can't handle Hiits that well.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. You're wondering what size you will be able to achieve? Because if so, that's not really something we can tell you, because it's different from person to person, and all we have to go on is two paragraphs of text.

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to fitness.se

First of all, hats off to what you've achieved thus far! Sounds like you're on the right path to becoming a more healthy version of yourself.

About you're question. If you're having doubts about your current shape, I'd advice you to do another bodyfat check. I'm assuming that on top of losing fat, you've gained some muscle. So you probably lost more fat than you think. I also advice you to make a progress picture, once every two to four weeks. This will make it easier to keep track of your progress.

How much smaller you're going to be once you lose 15kg more is hard for us to say but I think it's important to just judge your shape in the mirror from time to time and see how you're getting along, rather than looking at the number on the scale.

I hope this helps, if not please leave a comment!